# What's the best way to update Salesorce CRM upon SMS unsubscribe in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect

We track SMS Opt-ins/outs in Salesforce.

So, when someone texts STOP to Marketing Cloud - we need to update the CRM.

What's the best way to go about it?

Thinking maybe of adding AmpScript somewhere and use the UpdateSingleSalesforceObject method
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatesinglesalesforceobject.htm

but where would we add it?

Maybe there are better ways?

has anyone solved this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this depending on the frequency at which you need or want data made available to CRM. A few that come to mind to consider are:

1. AMPscript in the "Custom Response Text" of the Global/Custom STOP Keyword. This is the suggestion you made above. The STOP keyword allows you to define a custom response text which also supports AMPscript within the response field. The key thing to consider here is the context you'll have of the user on the inbound response. You will only have MOBILE_NUMBER so you'll have to consider the implications of how you associate that to a contact/lead/etc.

[image]

2. Batch extracts from MC and imports into CRM. In this case the data would have some latency but is another common way I've seen this data kept in sync.